# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu), pm2 node

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server, backend, pm2

I have nginx on my server, I am getting **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)** for my backend.
My backend is in Node.js and I have used **pm2** server.

My nginx config file:

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # angular app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/frontend/Form2Fill;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

I have hosted front-end and back-end on same domain, my front-end is working but back-end is giving **502 Bad Gateway**

I have tried restarting **nginx** and **pm2** both but it didn't resolve my issue.

When I tried getting status of pm2 server, it says status **errored**.

Comment: What does the nginx error log say?

Comment: Are you sure that your nodeJS application is running on 3000?, you can check the logs as @jordanm mentioned or execute `curl localhost:3000` which should return a response from the nodejs app if it works as expected.

Comment: 2020/11/05 12:32:25 [error] 29095#29095: *723 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.24.206, server: _, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upst$
2020/11/05 12:32:26 [error] 29095#29095: *723 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.24.206, server: _, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upst$
2020/11/05 12:32:26 [error] 29095#29095: *731 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.24.206, server: _, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upst$
this is error log @jordanm

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused, @mostafa node application is not running on port 3000 this time I think
But it was working before, It stops working after I deploy my code with minor change(only removed one API that was not in use)

Comment: Solved, node server is not starting because of error in code. process.env["USERNAME"] is returning undefined on server but it was working on my local system. 
I have run 'npm start' and then find the exact error on server console.